# How to put DetailTextLabel vertically center in cell of UITableView in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Actually i would like to set the position of detailtextlabel vertically center.
In my app detailtextlabel position goes to according to TextLabel(main lable) of cell. i.e it's allignment is top-right.

```
UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, cellIdentifier); 
cell.TextLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap; 
cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0; 
cell.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.PreferredCaption1; 
cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator; 
cell.TextLabel.Text = "some long text"; 
cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = childCount+"";
```

Comment: can you please post what you have tried. you will get a better response that way.

Comment: UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, cellIdentifier);    cell.TextLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0;    cell.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.PreferredCaption1;  cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
            cell.TextLabel.Text = "some long text";  cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = childCount+""    Actually i am not able to post screen shot due to reputation point problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement a custom table cell to get it to layout how you want. `TextLabel` and `DetailTextTabel` are automatically positioned, and it's hard to change their position easily.

I would recommend creating the cell in your storyboard using iOS auto-layout to position your views. You would define a custom class for the cell, and outlets for the new labels. You would use these outlets instead of the default `TextLabel` and `DetailsTextLabel` properties that iOS provides.

So, for example:

```
public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("YourCellID") as YourCell;
    cell.Update(passSomethingIn); //This public method would update your outlets
    return cell;
}
```

Then the `YourCell` class would have an `Update` method to change any values for each row.